# css - different <a href...> in a same size box

Tags: css

I have some links on my page. These links are surrounded by a border and background is set for them. They are in a box basicly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
a {
    background: #DDD;
    border: #BBB;
    padding:1px;
    width: 20em;    /*no effect*/
    height: 2em;    /*no effect*/
}
</style>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">1</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">1111111111111</a>
```

How can I make these boxes to have the same size?

Comment: `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`, they are currently inline, which ignores set widths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not understanding much but if you want the wrapper of same size than just use `display: block;` because `<a>` is an inline element hence you need to make it a block level element, or if you want the blocks inline, just use `display: inline-block;`

```
<style>
a {
    background: #DDD;
    border: #BBB;
    padding:1px;
    width: 20em;
    height: 2em;
    display: block; <------ Add This
}
</style>
```